# How to draw canvas in wordpress editor

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, canvas

I am trying to draw canvas in wordpress editor. 
In "Pages" with a custom made button for my plugin I can add the canvas using:

```
wp.media.editor.insert('<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">canvas test </canvas>');
```

but when I am trying to draw something in the canvas it does not work.

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Georgia";
ctx.fillText("test", 90, 50);
```

I'm not sure why it cannot find the canvas in order to draw it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the right way to do it.

The editor in "Pages" and "Posts" is in an iframe. 
So this is the way to access and draw in the canvas:

```
    var iframe = document.getElementById('content_ifr');
    var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var canvas = innerDoc.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "30px Georgia";
    ctx.fillText("test", 90, 50);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this plugin useful for you.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-shortcodes/

Please try it.